# Fill panels from SQL database (Webshop)

Tags: c#, sql, panel, webshop

have been struggling with this for a while now, the problem is i am trying to fill 1 panel with 1 product in my fictional webshop. I've found some code on the internet, but cant succeed in getting it to work properly.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectieString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectieStringWebshop"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection OphalenKoffieConnectie = new SqlConnection(ConnectieString);
        SqlCommand OphalenKoffieCommand = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader OphalenKoffieDataReader;

        try
        {
            OphalenKoffieConnectie.Open();
            OphalenKoffieCommand.Connection = OphalenKoffieConnectie;
            OphalenKoffieCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblArtikelen WHERE Categorie = Koffie";
            OphalenKoffieDataReader = OphalenKoffieCommand.ExecuteReader();
            OphalenKoffieDataReader.Read();

            foreach (DataRow row in OphalenKoffieDataReader)
            {
                Panel productPanel = new Panel();
                ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton
                {
                    ImageUrl = "~/ProductMedia/" + product.Image,
                    CssClass = "productImage",
                    PostBackUrl = string.Format("~/Pages/Product.aspx?id={0}", product.ID)
                };
                Label lblName = new Label
                {
                    Text = product.Name,
                    CssClass = "productName"
                };
                Label lblPrice = new Label
                {
                    Text = "£ " + product.Price,
                    CssClass = "productPrice"
                };

                pnlKoffie.Controls.Add(imageButton);
                pnlKoffie.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br/>" });
                pnlKoffie.Controls.Add(lblName);
                pnlKoffie.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br/>" });
                pnlKoffie.Controls.Add(lblPrice);

                pnlKoffie.Controls.Add(productPanel);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception OphalenKoffieFaal)
        {
            lblOphalenKoffieFaal.Text = OphalenKoffieFaal.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            OphalenKoffieConnectie.Close();
        }

    }
```

I want it to make a panel for each product it finds in the SQL DB where it has a specific category. I've stored a link and imagename of the image in my DB, images are located in "~/ProductMedia/" Anyone got any tips or tricks to get this working?

Comment: And what is not working with your current code? I bet you get an error message about a column not present in your table

Comment: https://gyazo.com/24bcaa0cb6b01eaca81a7d8404c560bc

Comment: I spoke too fast. Your code cannot be compiled at all because you are using undeclared variables and trying to access properties that doesn't exist in the SqlDataReader. Perhaps you need to read a tutorial on ADO.NET before trying to use some random code on internet